# Datatable export option is not working

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

Anyone can please help me why data table export option not working on the below-given link.

http://ec2-52-66-146-251.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com/Purvi/index.php/Ledger/ledger_view/18

jQuery:

```
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    "ordering": false,
    buttons: [{
        extend: "print",
        className: "btn dark btn-outline"
    }, {
        extend: "copy",
        className: "btn red btn-outline"
    }, {
        extend: "pdf",
        className: "btn green btn-outline"
    }, {
        extend: "excel",
        className: "btn yellow btn-outline "
    }, {
        extend: "csv",
        className: "btn purple btn-outline "
    }, {
        extend: "colvis",
        className: "btn dark btn-outline",
        text: "Columns"
    }],
});
```

Please help me why the data table export option is not working on given link.

Comment: have you define css `buttons.dataTables.min.css`  and 
 js `dataTables.buttons.min.js` files ?

Answer (score 1):

Replace your above code to this and try :

```
$('#example').DataTable({
    "ordering": false,
    buttons: [{
        extend: "print",
        className: "btn dark btn-outline"
    }, {
        extend: "copy",
        className: "btn red btn-outline"
    }, {
        extend: "pdf",
        className: "btn green btn-outline"
    }, {
        extend: "excel",
        className: "btn yellow btn-outline "
    }, {
        extend: "csv",
        className: "btn purple btn-outline "
    }, {
        extend: "colvis",
        className: "btn dark btn-outline",
        text: "Columns"
    }],
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you included this library files? 
- https://cdn.datatables.net/r/dt/jq-2.1.4,jszip-2.5.0,pdfmake-0.1.18,dt-1.10.9,af-2.0.0,b-1.0.3,b-colvis-1.0.3,b-html5-1.0.3,b-print-1.0.3,se-1.0.1/datatables.min.css"/>

You already added required files?
- https://cdn.datatables.net/r/dt/jq-2.1.4,jszip-2.5.0,pdfmake-0.1.18,dt-1.10.9,af-2.0.0,b-1.0.3,b-colvis-1.0.3,b-html5-1.0.3,b-print-1.0.3,se-1.0.1/datatables.min.js

You should also check this usage to include.

```
"dom": 'lBfrtip',
```